# Use autocomplete in masked-input primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete, maskedtextbox

I'd like to make a masked input field with autocompletion. In my example i have a field with article numbers `_.___.___`. I have also a list of often used articles. The user can select existing article numbers from the list and can add new articlenumbers.

How can i combine these two primefaces components?

Thanks for your help

Lepo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you have two possibilities: Create a custom component or set the inputmask manually via jQuery. I implemented the second method this way:

1. Use the normal Autocomplete Widget

   ```
   <h:form id="myPanel">
     <p:autoComplete id="number" value="#{myBean.number}" completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}" />
   </h:form>
   ```
2. Activate Inputmask via this little Javascript

   ```
   <script>
   //<![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(':input[id="myPanel:number_input"]').inputmask("mask", {"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});
   });
   //]]>
   </script>
   ```

(3. Make sure you have included the inputmask jquery library:)

```
    <script src="jquery.inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Although this solution does what it should do, i think the custom component would be the more cleaner way. 
Hope my Snippet helps you anyway.

Comment: it works in a normal h:inputtext, but unfortunately not in the p:autoComplete. Thanks for the help but any idea what it could be?

Comment: Watchout for the exact id, which is generated in your html page. Probably you have to add an _input to your id in the javascript like this:  $(':input[id="myPanel:number_input"]').inputmask("mask", {"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});

Comment: In Primefaces you don`t need to include jquery.inputmask.js because it`s already here. Just use another function: $(':input[id="number_input"]').mask("999-99-99", "");